# Script Not Working for User With Read Permissions

Tags: javascript, permissions, sharepoint-2013, access-denied

I have a workflow that sends emails out. When a user receives the email, there is a hyperlink called Review. When user clicks on Review, the value of the column called ReviewStatus on the Improvement List will be changed to Requested. I have a script below that handles this on a Content Editor Web Part:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("getSetListItem");
        var listItem;
        var list;
        var clientContext;
        var siteUrl = "https://contoso.com/process/";
        function getSetListItem() {
            this.clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
            if (this.clientContext != undefined && clientContext != null) {
                var webSite = clientContext.get_web();
                var itemID = parseInt(GetUrlKeyValue('ID'));
                this.list = webSite.get_lists().getByTitle("Improvement");
                this.listItem = list.getItemById(itemID);
                clientContext.load(this.listItem);
                this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadSuccess),
Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadFailed));
            }
        } 
        function OnLoadSuccess(sender, args) {
            var value = this.listItem.get_item("ReviewStatus");
            this.listItem.set_item("ReviewStatus", "Requested");
            this.listItem.update();
            this.clientContext.load(this.listItem);
            this.clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadSuccess1),
Function.createDelegate(this, this.OnLoadFailed));
        } 
        function OnLoadSuccess1(sender, args) {
            alert(this.listItem.get_item("ReviewStatus"));
        } 
        function OnLoadFailed(sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
        }

        </script>
```

The above works for me but I have Site Col Admin permissions. When a user with Read permissions clicks on the hyperlink it takes them to the page where the CEWP is and they get the below message:

[image]

I know it's permissions but what can I do to make it work for users who doesn't have the permissions? By the way, the client wants to keep the permissions to Read Only for users so there's nothing I can do about that.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By design, javascript code cannot run with elevated privileges because every user in nowadays browsers can just add javascript to edit (i'm talking browser developer tools).

That would of course be very risky for your project :)

You can create a farm solution if you want code to run in elevated privileges if you really don't want to change the permission settings.

If you want to keep your script, then you will have to modify the permissions for the users executing the scripts